# overflow-x: scroll does not scroll correctly

Tags: css, scroll

I want to be able to scroll horizontally trough some articles but it is not working. I try to put a border around the content so some of the content is cut off so I can scroll but the articles align vertically when I do this...

This is the code I'm using:

HTML:

```
                <a href="verhaal.html"> <img class="x"  src="images/haiku.jpeg" alt="mop"></a>

                <h3>Haiku</h3>
                <p>Rust, vrolijk, kort.</p>

                <img class="rating" src="images/rating.png" alt="sterren">

                <button class="down"></button>

            </article>


            <article>

                <img class="x" src="images/mop.jpeg" alt="mop">

                <h3>De mop</h3>
                <p>Licht, grappig, kort.</p>

                <img class="rating" src="images/rating.png" alt="sterren">

                <button class="down"></button>


            </article>
```

CSS:

```
 div#scroll1{
      border: solid;
      width: 24em;
      height: 22em;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      overflow-x: scroll;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the entire html code ? Or a bigger part because we can't see where is your div #scroll1.

Also, change your border in your css :
**border: 1px solid black**

Can you make a screenshot or a draw of what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 divs, one for scrolling and one for aligning the content in.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="scroll">
  <div id="alignment">
    <article>
      ...
    </article>
    <article>
      ...
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 24em;
  height: 24em;
}

#alignment {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Increase width depending on how many articles you wanna show */
  width: 240em;
  height: 24em;
}

article {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 24em;
  height: 22em;
}
```

Heres a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhrtueky/29/).